# How to split tag key and tag value

Tags: influxdb

I am trying to test the influxdb, not sure why is so hard to split the tag vs field

> INSERT interface_tracking, interface_id="TenGi4/1", router_name="Pe-Agg-2" interface_status="down", in=20,out=20,mac_count=2

I want interface_id and router_name as field and rest as tag.

Answer (score 0):

NM

I was using space after the key tag and field key_value.

```
INSERT interface_tracking,interface_id="TenGi4/1",router_name="Pe-Agg-2" interface_status="down",in=20,out=20,mac_count=2
```